# how to do verify using java.security.Signature

Tags: java, rsa, digital-signature

I have a key pair already, public and private. How do I actually use the `java.security.Signature` to do verification of a string I signed with one of the keys?

Edit:

I have both the keys as Strings. The verify method, it is actually

```
verify(byte[] signature)
```

The javadoc says:

> `verify(byte[] signature)` Indicates whether the given signature can be
>   verified using the public key or a certificate of the signer.

How would I make that signature recognize which public/private key to use for that verifying, before I call the verify method? In other words, how do I turn my string keys into key objects that would get accepted by signature?

Comment: Is there by any chance a method named `verify` in that class? If so perhaps you have a more specific question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Use `KeyFactory` to translate key specifications to objects.
2. Call `Signature.getInstance(algName)` to get a signature instance.
3. Use `Signature`'s `initVerify` method to associate a key for signature verification.
4. Use `update` to feed the `Signature` bytes.
5. Finally, call `verify`.
6. Profit

From the [`KeyFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyFactory.html) javadoc:

> The following is an example of how to use a key factory in order to instantiate a DSA public key from its encoding. Assume Alice has received a digital signature from Bob. Bob also sent her his public key (in encoded format) to verify his signature. Alice then performs the following actions:
>
> ```
> X509EncodedKeySpec bobPubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(bobEncodedPubKey);
> KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("DSA");
> PublicKey bobPubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(bobPubKeySpec);
> Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("DSA");
> sig.initVerify(bobPubKey);
> sig.update(data);
> sig.verify(signature);
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So in my case, I would change "DSA" to "RSA", right?

Comment: @sammiwei, I don't know whether it's `"RSASSA-PSS"` or what the appropriate algorithm name is to your situation, but you are correct in that you need to substitute the correct name for `"DSA"` in two places in that example.

Comment: Algorithm names -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Signature